# MVC Authorize Attribute validate JSON values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have the following code, which works fine with a URL of /Projects/{userId}/{Id}

but if i post the values up to the page with /Projects/ and JSON values of

```
{"userId":1234,"Id":145}
```

it will not pick up the JSON values, both UserId and Id are null.

the code is as follows

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    int documentIdfound, userIdFound;
    int? documentId = null;
    var documentIdRoute = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Id"];

    if (int.TryParse((string)documentIdRoute, out documentIdfound))
        documentId = documentIdfound;

    //if we havent found the ProjectId in the RouteData check the querystring. Just in case
    if (documentId == null)
    {
        documentIdRoute = httpContext.Request.QueryString["Id"];
        if (int.TryParse((string)documentIdRoute, out documentIdfound))
            documentId = documentIdfound;
    }

    var userIdRoute = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["userId"];

    int.TryParse((string)userIdRoute, out userIdFound);

    var gi = GetCurrentUser();

    try
    {
        var userFound = gi.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == userIdFound).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userFound != null)
        {
            return gi.IsUserValid(userFound.UserId, documentId.Value);
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AddErrorToDB(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be a Model Binder problem binding json to variables
You'll need to add a costum Json Model binder for that

Answer (score 0):

Try sending parameter values as strings:

`{'userId':'1234','Id':'145'}`

This will solve the problem.